# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() won't redirect

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have  a problem with my $urlRouterProvider.otherwise();

When emulated on android, the app launches on the artists state and not the welcome.

I don't see where the problem might come from.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ionicConfigProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $sceDelegateProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
    })

    .state('user',{
        url:'/user',
        templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
        controller: 'UserCtrl'
    })
    .state('settings',{
        url:'/settings',
        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html'
//        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
    })
    .state('artists',{
        url:'/artists',
        templateUrl: 'templates/artists.html',
        controller: 'ArtistsCtrl'
    })
    .state('artist',{
        url:'/artists/:artistId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/artist.html',
        controller: 'ArtistCtrl'
    })
    .state('search',{
        url:'/search',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');

}]);
```

thanks for any help !

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Have you perhaps set your emulator to launch with `/artists`?

Comment: I have no error @Gary

Comment: @Phil I don't think I have, how can I check that ?

Comment: Whats the path the browser opens with?

Comment: try adding this to your code. `app.run(['$state',function ($state){$state.transitionTo('welcome');}])` . This should work. Remember to use your `<base href='/'>` tag in the first line after <head> tag

Comment: @Gary no need for `<base>` if OP is not using HTML5 mode. Also, setting the app to always start on `/welcome`, regardless of request URI partially defeats the purpose of URL based routing so I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: I beleieve thats what he needs. Vieroli if you dont want to start all the time with welcome and start on whatever the requested state try removing the transitionTo line and it should solve your purpose.

Comment: I want to redirect users to welcome if they are not connected, I'll try that and come back to you guys !

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$stateProvider
.state("welcome", { url : '/welcome'})
```

Comment: I have an error : 
Error: 'rule' must be a function